# C++ assign array of ints to an empty array of ints same size

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment

I am very familiar with Java and this is allowed there. However it looks like it's not with C++. I'm getting an "invalid array assignment" when trying to assign valuesToGrab = updatingValues;.

```
//these are class attributes
int updatingValues[361] = {0};
int valuesToGrab[361] = {0};

//this is part of a function that is causing an error. 
for (unsigned int i=0; i < 10; i++) {

    //this fills values with 361 ints, and num_values gets set to 361. 
    sick_lms.GetSickScan(values,num_values);

    //values has 361 ints, but a size of 2882, so I copy all the ints to an array
    //of size 361 to "trim" the array.
    for(int z = 0; z < num_values; z++){
        updatingValues[z] = values[z];
    }

    //now I want to assign it to valuesToGrab (another program will be 
    //constantly grabbing this array, and it can't grab it while it's being
    //populated above or there will be issues
    valuesToGrab = updatingValues; // THROWING ERROR
}
```

I don't want to have to iterate through updatingValues and add it to valuesToGrab one by one, but if I have to I will. Is there a way I can assign it in one function with C++?

Thanks,

Comment: For a C-Style array [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) or [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/)

Comment: "trimming" the array seems totally unnecessary.  Trimming and then copying, doubly so.

Comment: You really, really should learn about memory management in C & C++.

Comment: Also, your comment 
"//now I want to assign it to valuesToGrab (another program will be 
//constantly grabbing this array, and it can't grab it while it's being
//populated above or there will be issues"

strongly implies the need for process synchronization via mutex or critical section.

Comment: Thank you guys. I agree that the trimming is unnecessary and I knew I had to look into threading with C++ sometime. I've also heard that memory management is very important in C++ so I will look into that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard idiom for copying in C++ is

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::copy(values, values+num_values, updatingValues);
```

make sure `updatingValues` is large enough or you will get overruns and bad things will happen.

That said in C++ we generally use a std::vector for this sort of task.

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<int> updatingValues=values; //calls vectors copy constructor
```

I vector does everything an array does (including static initalization in C++11), but has a well define interface. with iterators, size, empty, resize, push_back and more.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

EDIT
It is also worth noting that you can combine vector and arrays.

```
std::vector<int> vect(my_array, my_array+10);
//or
std::vector<int> another_vector;
...
another_vector.assign(my_array, my_array+10);//delayed population
```

and visa-versa

```
std::copy(vect.begin(), vect.end(), my_array); //copy vector into array.
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the idiomatic container to use in place of arrays is `std::vector`. With `vector` or with arrays, you can use the `std::copy()` function from the `<algorithm>` header, which is the preferred way of copying containers of any sort in C++. With `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> updatingValues, valuesToGrab;

// Ensure the vector has sufficient capacity to accept values.
updatingValues.resize(361);

// Copy values from the array into the vector.
std::copy(values, values + 361, updatingValues.begin());
//        Source begin & end;   Destination begin.

// Copy one vector to another.
valuesToGrab = updatingValues;
```

With arrays:

```
std::copy(valuesToGrab, valuesToGrab + 361, updatingValues);
```

Again with just arrays, if you are going for more of a C style, you can use the C standard library function `memcpy()`, from `<cstdlib>`:

```
memcpy(valuesToGrab, updatingValues, 361 * sizeof(int));
//     Destination;  Source;         Number of bytes.
```

With `memcpy()` (and its cousin, `memmove()`), you must be careful about the size of the elements you’re copying; if you say `361` instead of `361 * sizeof(int)`, you’ll copy 361 bytes, not 361 `int`s’ worth of bytes—a big difference.

Comment: You should clarify that the `memcpy` applies only if you want to copy from an array to another array (although you *can* use it to copy between vectors of PODs if you get a pointer to the involved elements).

Comment: Ok, +1 :) (also to counterbalance the IMHO unjustified -1)

Comment: you can use vector::assign instead of copy. it will allocate the space for you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think this will do what you're looking for because `valuesToGrab = updatingValues;` will overwrite your `valuesToGrab` every cycle of the outer loop.

Assuming you did want to do this though, and you didn't want to change to a vector:

```
std::copy(updatingValues, updatingValues+361, valuesToGrab);
```

will do it.  You can treat a normal array just like a std:: container in any std::algorithm, the pointers count as random access iterators.

Rethink your design though, you shouldn't need to "trim" and you probably don't need to copy.

Comment: That is what I want to do. I just want valuesToGrab to have the most recent complete scan. If I don't have this array and instead have a method that gets updatingValues, then it might get it while it's getting re-filled and return a half-full array.

You're right about the trimming. I think I can just ignore that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that arrays are implemented as pointers in C and C++.

In particular an array on the stack can be visualized as a pointer to a constant location in memory that has the capacity that you requested for the array.  This memory is on the stack.  When you try `valuesToGrab = updatingValues`, you could think of this as trying to copy the address of `updatingValues` to the variable `valuesToGrab`.  This is **NOT** attempting a deep copy, which you seem to be attempting.  However, `valuesToGrab` points to a constant location in memory and cannot be updated.  The standard is a little more specific on this and explicitly forbids the assignment of arrays, which is why you're getting the specific error that you're seeing.

You will need to use a loop or something like `std::copy` or C's `memcpy` to copy the values from one array to the other.

Comment: Arrays aren’t pointers. The name of an array is convertible to a pointer in expressions.